# How do I copy data from one Azure database table to a different Azure database table and also convert data types?

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have to copy data from one table to another, the tables are held in two different databases within Azure.  I did a quick search for answers to this and whilst a query seems fairly straight forward i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (make, model, type, serial)

SELECT the_make, the_model, the_type, ref_no

FROM database2.dbo.table2
```

I encountered issues because I'm using Azure.

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Reference to database and/or
>   server name in 'database2.dbo.table2' is not supported in this version of
>   SQL Server.

The above issue led me to the Cross-Database Queries articles.  My requirements are a little more complicated than some of the scenarios provided and I need some help in making it work.

I also need to convert some columns such as `reg_no` which is a 'string' to an 'int' and then copy the value to the 'serial' column.

My question is, what the best way to create a script for this that allows me to reference both databases without any errors, copy the data and convert the columns at the same time?  I tried the simple way of exporting data and importing it, editing the mappings for the columns, it wasn't that good I found and was causing problems all over the place.

Any guidance is appreciated on this.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because there's no linked server by default. You'll need to add it, in order to access the secondary db server. Here's a link about how to do it:

https://www.sqlshack.com/create-linked-server-azure-sql-database/

In terms of the transformation. It depends on many factors e.g. amount of rows, frequency, etc..

Usually the best alternative is by using an external tool (ETL) such as SSIS / Azure Data Factory because you can schedule it's execution and get the status of each execution.

Comment: I didn't know that existed, thanks.  I can't work with that tutorial because I don't have the 'Database Objects' element in my tree and there is no option to switch it on, attempting to modify SSMS to turn it on doesn't work as there's no option for it.  I'm using SSMS 18.4

Comment: you can do it using regular t-sql. Just look for linked server and SQL database